# What is the mathematical equation/function for lithium ion battery recharge time in the constant-voltage phase?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, modeling

I'm trying to program a simple two phase battery recharge model in Python where the constant current (CC) phase is linear with respect to recharge time and state of charge (charge capacity).

However, to model the constant voltage (CV) phase, I need a suitable nonlinear equation for constant voltage state of charge (CVSoC) as a function of recharge time (t), current (I) and voltage (V): CVSoC = f(t,I,V). Is it logarithmic, logistic, polynomial?

I'm having a hard time finding any basic approximation online that doesn't jump in the weeds of battery chemistry and complex modeling.

[image]

Comment: Get a bunch of samples into Excel and ask it to approximate it for you.

Comment: Or use those samples to make a look up table. Ain't no one got time for non-linear hocus pocus.

Comment: found this ... https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_find_a_fitting_equation_for_the_discharge_curve_of_a_battery

Comment: The plot picture I included is notional. I don't have samples to put in Excel, since I'm looking for a general formula for d_capacity / d_time.

@jsotola that paper is for discharge. I need recharge.